# Sudden acceleration

Tags: engine

my Mahindra Bolero suddenly accelerates itself to full throttle, the only way im able to stop this is by switching off the engine & restarting. what is causing this?

Comment: throttle cable sticking? does this happen from idle or does it feel like the gas pedal is stuck in a certain spot? im guessing this car is stick shift and goes "full throttle" when you press the clutch right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that car is drive by wire, which means it has sensors in the gas pedal and the throttle body. Both are designed with redundant sensors that check each other to prevent just the situation you are describing. First step would be to connect a scanner through the obd and check for DTCs.

Comment: What does DTC stand for, if I may ask?

Comment: Diagnostic Trouble Codes